# Fetching Emails from IMAP Server Effective Way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap

I am currently developing a Ruby on Rails app where I can manage emails on it. Emails have come from my own hosting server (eg. john@example.com), it isn't gmail or yahoo etc.

So, I am using this method :

```
<% imap.select("INBOX") %>
<% imap.search(["NOT", "RECENT"]).each do |message_id| %>
<% envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"] %>
<% body = imap.fetch(message_id,'BODY[TEXT]')[0].attr['BODY[TEXT]'] %>
<%= envelope.subject %>
<%= body.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

Which is working fine, but the problem is, when the emails came more than 10, it become very slow to load, and sometimes return error timeout, which makes the application not load.

Are there any ways (or gem) to handle a bunch of emails to read at one time?

Since I think the way that I am using now is not effective.

Thank you.

Comment: A quick look at the documentation for the one you're using suggests code along the lines of messages=imap.search(...); map.fetch(messages, 'BODY[TEXT]).each do ...

Comment: Where I can see that documentation? Since I didn't see it.

Comment: I've already closed the browser tab... https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-fetch has the same text. It doesn't say "calling fetch once with an array is faster than 100 times with an integer" but that will be the case. Fewer network roundtrips.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on arnt's answer, I found that fetching first in array will be faster than my previous way. I still not sure sure if this is the best one, so if anyone found a better way, please let me know.

This is my new code.

```
<% surat = imap.search(["SINCE", @mail_date]) %>
<% arr_envelop = imap.fetch(surat, "ENVELOPE") %>
<% body_envelop = imap.fetch(surat, "RFC822.TEXT") %>
```